# Android FCM registerToken function is not running

Tags: android, logging

Log is show until "Refreshed token:......", logs "send out 0" and the rest is not appear at all...mean registerToken() is not running at all but how come?

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh(){
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    registerToken(token);
    Log.v("myApp", "token is " + token);
    Log.v("myApp","Refreshed token: " + token);
}

private void registerToken(String token) {
    Log.v("myApp","send out 0");
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("Token",token)
            .build();
    Log.d("myApp","send out 1");
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://server.com/register.php")
            .post(body)
            .build();
    Log.d("myApp","send out 2");
    try {
        client.newCall(request).execute();
        Log.d("myApp","send out succ");
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("myApp","send out failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have registerd your app in firebase console

Inorder for getting registration token just add below code in your activity or fragment

```
 String deviceGCMToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

now you can implement webservice for sending registration token to server